# How to associate two inputs in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.container select').each(function(){
      $(this).on('change', function(){
          var selectedVal = $(this).val();
            //console.log(selectedVal);
        });
    });
 $('input').on('change', function () {
    var sum = 0;
    $('input').each(function() {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });
    $('.total span').html(sum);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='full'>
     <input type='number' value=''>
     <select name='select1'>
        <option value='a1'>A1</option>
        <option value='a2'>A2</option>
      </select>
  </div>
  <div class='full'>
     <input type='number' value=''>
     <select name='select2'>
        <option value='a1'>A1</option>
        <option value='a2'>A2</option>
      </select>
  </div>
  <div class='full'>
     <input type='number' value=''>
     <select name='select3'>
        <option value='a1'>A1</option>
        <option value='a2'>A2</option>
      </select>
  </div>
  <div class='total'>
     Total nr: <span>5(2 A1, 3 A2)</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible that on change of the select and the input of type number to modify the total number like in the code above using JavaScript/jQuery?
Can anyone help me with this please.

On every change on the inputs or select fields I need to calculate total number of A1 and total number of A2. Hope this make sense. And display them beside the total number.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2so9wp0y/9/)

Comment: i don't get what you want to achieve....total number should be the result of the selected values?

Comment: I need to calculate the total number of values from each input type number. And separately, depending on select, the number of each option selected. I hope this make sense

Comment: @messerbill, I've updated my question a bit. Maybe now you understand much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't give you the full code but I tried to provide some logic for what you want.I think you want some thing like this:

```js
//create a json to collect the sum of numbers
var number = {
  a1: 0,
  a2: 0,
  a1_count:0,
  a2_count:0
};
//check in select change 
$(".select").change(function() {

//flush previous calculation before using again 
   number.a1=0,number.a2=0,number.a1_count=0,number.a2_count=0;
   
//check all the select value and get the corresponding input value 
  $(".select").each(function() {
    var valueType = $(this).val();
    if (valueType == "a1") {
      number[valueType+"_count"]=number[valueType+"_count"]+1;  
      number[valueType] = number[valueType] + parseInt($(this).prev().val()||0);
    } else if (valueType == "a2") {
number[valueType+"_count"]=number[valueType+"_count"]+1;
      number[valueType] = number[valueType] + parseInt($(this).prev().val()||0);
    }

  });
  
  $("#total").html('Total:'+(number.a1+number.a2)+',A1:'+number.a1+'('+number.a1_count+'),A2:'+number.a1+'('+number.a2_count+')');
 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='full'>
    <input type='number' value=''>
    <select name='select1' class='select'>
      <option value='a1'>A1</option>
      <option value='a2'>A2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class='full'>
    <input type='number' value=''>
    <select name='select2' class='select'>
      <option value='a1'>A1</option>
      <option value='a2'>A2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class='full'>
    <input type='number' value=''>
    <select name='select3' class='select'>
      <option value='a1'>A1</option>
      <option value='a2'>A2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class='total' id="total">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've made some changes to my question, added extra code. I know how to calculate the total. In the same way I calculate the total, I need to add beside the total number, in paranthesis, the total number of each selected value. @Anand Sing, I've also added a JsFiddle to my updated question.

Comment: opps forgot to flush check now @Anonymous

Answer (score 0):

This will work for any arbitrary list in the select.

```
function change() {
  var res = {}, fulls = $('.container .full');
  fulls.each(function(index){
    var selected = $(this).find('select > option:selected').text();
    if (! res[selected]) res[selected] = 0;
    res[selected] += 1*$(this).find('input[type="number"]').val();
  });
  var detail = "", total = 0;
  for(prop in res) {
    if (res.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      try {
        var val = 1*res[prop];
        detail += ", "+val+" "+prop;
        total += val;
      }catch(e){}
    }
  }
  $('.total > span').text(""+total+" ("+detail.substr(2)+")");
}

$().add('.container .full input[type="number"]')
   .add('.container .full select[name^="select"]')
   .on('change', change);
```